# IN/EXISTS predicate sub-queries can only be used in Filter/Join

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 3 views `dataset1`, `current` and `all`. This is the query I have now

```
SELECT
     t1.id,
     t1.year,
     t1.day,
     t1.month,
     (CASE WHEN t2.id is null then false else true end) as id_present,
     (CASE WHEN ((NOT (t1.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id
                                FROM all a
                                WHERE a.dates = current_date - Interval '2' day))) 
                 AND 
                 ((t1.click_date = current_date) OR ((t1.count > 0) AND (t1.click_date < (current_date - INTERVAL  '12' MONTH)))))
            THEN 'Action1' 
            WHEN ((NOT (t1.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id 
                                   FROM all a
                                   WHERE a.dates = current_date - Interval '2' day)))
                    AND (t1.count > 0) 
                    AND (t1.click_date < (current_date - INTERVAL  '12' MONTH))) 
            THEN 'Action2' 
            ELSE 'Action3' END) actions
FROM dataset1 t1 LEFT JOIN current t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Now the error I am facing is
`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: IN/EXISTS predicate sub-queries can only be used in Filter/Join and a few commands:`

This query is working fine in basic SQL but not in spark SQL and I understand that it is because of me using `NOT IN` in `CASE WHEN`. What is the alternative to this query in order to avoid this error?

Comment: Please update your query to explicit show which table these columns belong to: 'dates, count, click_date, current_date'

Comment: @TrungDuong Just updated. Thanks! `current_date` is an Athena Function

Comment: I've add an answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spark,

1. If the number of distinct ids in `all` is small, you can use [collect_set()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_contains) function to create the distinct id array, [cross join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html) dataset1 and then [array_contains()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_contains) function to check whether id in distinct id array.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
     t1.id,
     year,
     day,
     month,
     (CASE WHEN t2.id is null then false else true end) as id_present,
     (CASE WHEN ((NOT array_contains(dia.distinct_id_array,t1.id))) 
                 AND 
                 ((click_date = current_date) OR ((count > 0) AND (click_date < (current_date - INTERVAL  '12' MONTH)))))
            THEN 'Action1' 
            WHEN ((NOT array_contains(dia.distinct_id_array,t1.id)))
                    AND (count > 0) 
                    AND (click_date < (current_date - INTERVAL  '12' MONTH))) 
            THEN 'Action2' 
            ELSE 'Action3' END
    ) as actions
FROM dataset1 t1 
LEFT JOIN current t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id
CROSS JOIN (
(SELECT collect_set(id) as distinct_id_array
 FROM all
 WHERE dates = current_date - Interval '2' day
) dia
```

2. If the number of distinct id in `all` is big, you need to use [left join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html) with `dataset1` and group by to generate a is_in_all flag for each id in t1.

Here is the query:

```
WITH id_flag (
SELECT
    dataset1.id,
    COUNT(all.id) > 0 as is_in_all
FROM
    dataset1
LEFT JOIN
    all
ON
    dataset1.id = all.id
GROUP BY dataset1.id
)

SELECT
     t1.id,
     year,
     day,
     month,
     (CASE WHEN t2.id is null then false else true end) as id_present,
     (CASE WHEN ((NOT is_in_all)) 
                 AND 
                 ((click_date = current_date) OR ((count > 0) AND (click_date < (current_date - INTERVAL  '12' MONTH)))))
            THEN 'Action1' 
            WHEN ((NOT is_in_all))
                    AND (count > 0) 
                    AND (click_date < (current_date - INTERVAL  '12' MONTH))) 
            THEN 'Action2' 
            ELSE 'Action3' END
    ) as actions
FROM dataset1 t1 
LEFT JOIN current t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id
JOIN id_flag
ON
   t1.id = id_flag.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How do you define small and big here? If we do `collect_set`,  this set would contain around 200K ids.

Comment: Hi @Mikasa, this depends on your dev env. 10K should be a safe threshold to distinguish small and big in most env.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use this query. It's a modified version of your query, I've moved sub-queries in your `CASE WHEN` to `JOIN` clause, and replace `NOT IN` with `NOT EXISTS` expression.

```
SELECT
     t1.id,
     t1.year,
     t1.day,
     t1.month,
     (CASE WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN false ELSE true END) AS id_present,
     (CASE WHEN (t3.id IS NOT NULL  
                 AND 
                 ((t1.click_date = current_date) OR ((t1.count > 0) AND (t1.click_date < (current_date - INTERVAL  '12' MONTH)))))
            THEN 'Action1' 
            WHEN (t3.id IS NOT NULL
                  AND (t1.count > 0) 
                  AND (t1.click_date < (current_date - INTERVAL  '12' MONTH))) 
            THEN 'Action2' 
            ELSE 'Action3' END) actions
FROM dataset1 t1 
     LEFT JOIN current t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
     LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT id
        FROM   dataset1 t
        WHERE  NOT EXISTS 
              (SELECT 1
               FROM all a
               WHERE t.id = a.id AND a.dates = current_date - Interval '2' day)
       ) t3 ON t1.id = t3.id
```

Comment: Is that `Select 1` inside `WHERE NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: Yes, since we only need to check ID in table `dataset1` which is not existed in table `all`, so it only needs to `SELECT 1`